# Can coaxial rotors be mounted on a piston engine like the Lycoming O-320?

Tags: piston-engine, rotorcraft, turboshaft, lycoming

What are the drawbacks of this compared to coaxial configuration with a turboshaft engine?

Comment: Even on piston engine helicopters the rotors are not directly connected to the engine, they go through a transmission. I don't see why you couldn't, although the O-320 probably wouldn't have enough power to turn two full-size rotors.

Comment: It is theoretically possible to mount coaxial helicopter rotors on any engine, but it would not be economically feasible on a small engine like an O-320. Turboshaft engines typically have much more power than an O-320. Why would you compare an O-320 engine to a turboshaft engine?

Comment: What the hell... Once again a totally legit question here, and someone gives it a minus one. Come on guys/gals... at least have the courtesy of commenting why you think this is a bad question!

Answer (score 3):

Stan Hiller's earliest helo designs were coaxial and used relatively small 4-cylinder aircraft engines to drive the coax transmission, so it is indeed possible to power a small coaxial helicopter with a relatively small piston engine.

Hiller also found that autorotating a coax main rotor blade setup was difficult and so his later designs used a more conventional single main rotor blade and a tail rotor.

Comment: That's interesting about the autorotation problems.  Must've been related to the mechanism he was using to get differential torque for yaw control?

Comment: do not know... -NN

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Earliest Kamov production helos - Ka-8 and Ka-10 - were powered by piston engines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamov_Ka-8